# "pointer being freed was not allocated" How can I find my wrong access to memory?

Tags: c++, memory

Firstly, I have to print the value of Funcion "Ranking" which of parameter is Stack!
But my compiler says [image]
I think that I delete memory which is not allocated. But, I can't find when I delete that memory....
Please help me the point I wrongly access memory.

P.S. I want to make a program that receive ints or strings and, put ints or strings into stack.
And use Ranking function as a Stack, the result would be, 
For ints, how many numbers in stack which exceed first number of stack . 
For strings, how many strings in stack which are later order than first string of stack.(The order of string objects is determined in the lexicographic order.) 
For example, if inputs are 4 1 +2 5 3 -1 6  and the results is 2 (because 5 and 6 are bigger than first 4)
For example, if inputs are "to be or not to be" the results is 0 ( because there is no later order string than "to")

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

const size_t SIZE = 100;

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Stack
{
public:
    Stack(size_t size = SIZE);
    Stack(const Stack<T>& s);
    const Stack<T>& operator = (const Stack<T>& s); ~Stack();
    bool isfull();
    bool isEmpty();
    void push(T d);
    T pop();
    T Elem(size_t i);
//  int Ranking(T obj);
private:
    T *_data;
    size_t _top, _size;
};

template <class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(size_t size) : _top(0), _size(size)
{
    _data = new T[size];
}

template <class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(const Stack<T>& s) : _top(s._top), _size(s._size)
{
    if (_data) delete[] _data;
    _size = s._size;
    _top = s._top;
    _data = new T[_size];
    for (int i = 0; i < _size; ++i)
        _data[i] = s._data[i];
}

template <class T>
Stack<T>::~Stack()
{
    delete [] _data;
}

template <class T>
bool Stack<T>::isfull()
{
    return _top == _size;
}

template <class T>
bool Stack<T>::isEmpty()
{
    return _top == 0;
}

template <class T>
void Stack<T>::push(T d)
{
    if (! isfull())
        _data[_top++] = d;
}

template <class T>
T Stack<T>::pop()
{
    if (! isEmpty())
        return _data[--_top];
    throw -1;
}


template <class T>
T Stack<T>::Elem(size_t i)
{
    return _data[i];
}

template <class T>
int Ranking(T obj)
{
    int k = 0;
    while(!obj.isEmpty())
    {
        if(obj.Elem(0).compare(obj.pop()) < 0 )
            k++;
    }
    return k;
}

int main(void)
{
    int k = 0;
    int value = 0;
    int num;
    string s;
    string line;
    Stack<string> strs;
    Stack<string> temps;
    vector<int> nums;

    while (getline(cin, line))
    {
        istringstream ins(line);
        while (ins >> s)
        {
            strs.push(s);
        }
        nums.push_back(Ranking(strs));
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (_data) delete[] _data;` -- Why are you attempting to `delete[]` in the copy constructor?  The object is brand new -- there is nothing to delete.  Get rid of that line of code.  I also don't see where you implemented the assignment operator for `Stack`.

Comment: And you don't need to initialize `top` and `size` twice each in the copy constructor.

Comment: And I would make the copy constructor deleted instead of implementing it. You shouldn't need to copy stacks around.

Answer (score 1):

In the body of your copy constructor, `_data` is initially uninitialised. `if (_data)` has undefined behaviour, which you have observed as `delete[]`ing an arbitrary pointer value.

There is never a previous allocation in a new object, so you don't need to `delete[]` anything. You declare (in a non-traditional way) but don't define a copy assignment operator.

I've also implemented a move constructor, which can reduce the number of copies you need.

Most of the bodies of your constructors can go, or be moved to the member initialiser. It is better to use a pre-defined algorithm rather than do it yourself.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

template <class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(size_t size) : _data(new T[size]), _top(0), _size(size)
{}

template <class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(const Stack<T>& s) : _data(new T[s._size]), _top(s._top), _size(s._size)
{
    std::copy_n(s._data, s._size, _data);
}

template <class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(Stack<T>&& s) : _data(std::exchange(s._data, nullptr)), _top(s._top), _size(s._size)
{
}

template <class T>
Stack<T>& Stack<T>::operator=(Stack<T> s) // nb: by-value argument, copies or moves
{
    std::swap(_data, s._data);
    _size = s._size;
    _top = s._top;
    return *this;
}
```